# Remapping keys in type

Tags: typescript

I want to create a type (`U`) that will be defined as having the keys of some given type `T` where `T` extends `Object`. The values of this new type will be defined as functions which will take in the value type for that key on the original type `T` and return the same type.

For instance if I had the type `I1`:

```js
interface I1 {
  a: number;
  b: Date;
}
```

Then `U<I1>` would be equal to:

```js
{
  a: (x: number) => number;
  b: (x: Date) => Date;
}
```

I did look at a few options with things like `keyof`, but I haven't yet figured out how best to do this. I tried, for instance:

```js
export type U<T extends {}, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]> = Record<K, (x: V) => V>;
```

But then you need to define explicit types for each of the generics. It seems like it's possible to remap keys in ts 4 with [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as), but right now I'm stuck on 3.7.1.

Any thoughts on how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 7):

I think something like this should work:

```
type U<T> = {
    [Prop in keyof T]: (x: T[Prop]) => T[Prop];
}
```

You can test it with:

```
type Test = U<I1>;
```

When you hover over `Test` you should see the desired signature.